# How much he is going to serve in prison for his crime?

Tags: ending, the-machinist

After Trevor Reznik reported himself to the police (as a criminal who killed a kid by accident in a hit-and-run case), how much jail time is he going to serve?

I just need an assumption. I am from China and I'm not familiar with US laws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The film 'The Machinist' was set in [California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machinist). Given that another person was killed in the accident (a child, no less), and that Reznik is intending to make a full confession (e.g. that he was distracted by reaching for his cigarette lighter) it's reasonably likely that he would be facing a felony charge for the accident:

> ...the prosecutor may choose to try it as a misdemeanor or a felony
>   ...usually depending on the facts of the case and the defendant's
>   criminal history.
>
> If felony hit and run is tried as a misdemeanor, the maximum penalties
>   are a fine of between one thousand dollars ($1,000) and ten thousand
>   dollars ($10,000), and/or up to one (1) year in county jail. If the
>   accident resulted in a death or a permanent, serious injury, in most
>   cases the defendant will need to serve at least ninety (90) days in
>   jail.
>
> But if it is prosecuted as a felony, felony hit and run carries
>   penalties of a fine of between one thousand dollars ($1,000) and ten
>   thousand dollars ($10,000)...plus sixteen (16) months to three (3)
>   years in state prison. **If someone (other than the defendant) was
>   killed or suffered a permanent, serious injury in the accident, the
>   state prison sentence rises to two (2) to four (4) years.** - <sub><sup>[SHOUSE CALIFORNIA LAW GROUP](http://www.shouselaw.com/felonyhr.html)</sup></sub>

So the best guess is that with a full confession and a guilty plea, he'd probably be serving the lower end of that sentence (2 years). Assuming he then demonstrated "[good conduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_conduct_time)", he would get a discount on his sentence of around 1-200 days, meaning that he would be **out of jail in around one and a half years.**

Comment: Obviously, he might end up with a judge that hates him and a crap lawyer and have to serve the full four years.

Comment: Didn't he go on without confessing for a long time though?  That'd work against him.

Comment: @Andrew - Yes, it would almost certainly result in the prosecution seeking a felony charge. Beyond that, his abject confession and pathetic willingness to seek absolution would go down very well in court.